# Illegal syntax error in code window for all BIML scripts

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ssis-2012, biml

I am wondering if Illegal syntax error is expected in the code window or its just me? It just not recognizes code directives <# #> and gives illegal sytax error everywhere I have c#scripts embedded.

Eg:

```
<#@ template language="C#"#>
```

This single line gives me 3 syntax errors

1. At first occurrence of '#' says *Illegal syntax. Expecting valid
   start name character*.
2. At 'template' it gives me error  *Missing
   attribute value on attribute 'template'.
3. At 2nd occurance of '#' it
   give error *Character '#', hexadecimal value x023 is illegal in xml
   namespace.

Dispite of this syntax error, my biml scripts complies without any problem, unless there is a genuine problem. This is so annoying to write code especially when I am debugging to fix genuine code.

Is this expected? can we get rid of this? I have installed 1.7.0 version of BIDSHelper (which is latest in downloads) and using SSIS 2012.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your whole file and the error?  Is it simply that it is giving you the squiggly red line underneath?

Comment: Yes, its just the red line, like I said in my op my biml complies even with these lines showing in code window. I am mobile can't share code but it shows error for ANY code within where I use <##>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BIDSHelper does not correctly check the syntax for code snippets.  As far as I am aware there is no solution to this using your current set up.

If you upgraded your SSDT ([as 2012 is currently not working](https://varigence.com/Forums?threadID=9637)) you could install [BimlExpress](https://varigence.com/BimlExpress) instead which has all the same features as BIDSHelper (regarding what it can do with Biml files) and has proper syntax highlighting and error checking.

Further info here: http://www.cathrinewilhelmsen.net/2016/04/21/get-started-bimlexpress/